# How to find missing coefficients of parabola rotated $30^{\circ}$ counterclockwise?

Tags: conic-sections

[image]

I tried using the formula $\cot(2\theta)=\dfrac{A-C}{B}$, and got it down to $A-C=2$.

I would need a second equation to find the values of those coefficients.
So I tried this instead:

To remove $xy$ terms from the equation, we use the formulas$$
\begin{cases}
x=x'\cos(\theta)-y'\sin(\theta)\\
y=x'\sin(\theta)+y'\cos(\theta)
\end{cases}.$$
After simplifying and substituting into the equation, I got this:
$$A=C+6\sqrt{3}-\frac{13}{2},\ A=C-\frac{7}{2}, C=\frac{A}{4}-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3C}{4}-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}+2\sqrt{3}.$$

But when I tried solving these equations, I get "no solutions".

What is the valid method of finding the values of $A$ and $C$?

Comment: Hint: The quadratic terms must form a perfect square, so $AC=3$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not quite sure what that means sorry :(

Comment: Why do they have to form a perfect square? Is there a rule for this?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case).

Comment: How do you tell a parabola from another conic ?

Comment: https://fl01000126.schoolwires.net/cms/lib/FL01000126/Centricity/Domain/261/Ch9_Section4.pdf

Comment: I just read the above link, and it says that for a parabola, $AC = 0$

Comment: But @Jan-MagnusØkland's Wiki link shows that $b^2 - 4ac = 0$. Which equation should I use?

Comment: $B^2-4AC=0$ is the discriminant of $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$ and tells you when it's a square as you can see from the quadratic formula for say $\frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: And $AC=0$ in your link says the same in the case where $B=0$; you can only have $x^2$ or $y^2$ but not both and they are squares.